# Export the Result of a Stored Procedure to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008 and trying to export to Excel. I have successfully done this using the export wizard however I am trying to do this using an executable query. Here is the code that I am trying to use:

```
    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;

    GO

    RECONFIGURE;

    GO

    EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;

    GO

    RECONFIGURE;

    GO




    USE [RolandTest]

    INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\Users\Roland\Desktop\ExcelExportsPractice\EEPractice.xlsx;','Select * from [GasEUR$]')
    SELECT     rcl.CaseCaseId AS CaseId, cc.Label AS CaseName, cc.Field, cc.Reservoir, cc.County, cc.State, cc.OperatorName, cc.BaseApiCode, cc.Location, cc.CaseType, 
                  rcat.Label AS Category, rclass.Label AS Class, ps.ReportDate, cs.CaseDiscountFactor, corp.Label AS Scenario, cct.Label AS CorpCaseType, cp.Label AS MajorPhase, 
                  rcl.SortId, ProjProject.Label AS Project
    FROM         PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_465 AS rcl INNER JOIN
                  CaseCases AS cc ON rcl.CaseCaseId = cc.CaseCaseId INNER JOIN
                  Corp.RsvCategory AS rcat ON cc.RsvCatSortNumber = rcat.RsvCatSortNumber INNER JOIN
                  Corp.RsvClass AS rclass ON cc.RsvClassSortNumber = rclass.RsvClassSortNumber INNER JOIN
                  CaseScenario AS cs ON cc.CaseCaseId = cs.CaseCaseId AND cc.CaseCaseId = cs.CaseCaseId AND cc.CaseCaseId = cs.CaseCaseId AND 
                  cc.CaseCaseId = cs.CaseCaseId INNER JOIN
                  ProjectScenario AS ps ON cs.ProjProjectId = ps.ProjProjectId AND cs.CorpScenarioId = ps.CorpScenarioId AND cs.ProjProjectId = ps.ProjProjectId AND 
                  cs.CorpScenarioId = ps.CorpScenarioId AND cs.ProjProjectId = ps.ProjProjectId AND cs.CorpScenarioId = ps.CorpScenarioId AND 
                  cs.ProjProjectId = ps.ProjProjectId AND cs.CorpScenarioId = ps.CorpScenarioId AND cs.ProjProjectId = ps.ProjProjectId AND 
                  cs.CorpScenarioId = ps.CorpScenarioId AND cs.ProjProjectId = ps.ProjProjectId AND cs.CorpScenarioId = ps.CorpScenarioId INNER JOIN
                  CorpScenario AS corp ON ps.CorpScenarioId = corp.CorpScenarioId INNER JOIN
                  CorpCaseType AS cct ON cc.CaseType = cct.CorpCaseTypeId INNER JOIN
                  ModelPhaseConfiguration AS mpc ON cs.ModelPhaseConfigurationId = mpc.ModelPhaseConfigurationId INNER JOIN
                  CorpProduct AS cp ON mpc.MajorPhaseId = cp.CorpProductId INNER JOIN
                  ProjProject ON ps.ProjProjectId = ProjProject.ProjProjectId
    WHERE     (cs.CorpScenarioId = 1) AND (cs.Deleted = 0)
    GROUP BY rcl.CaseCaseId, cc.Label, cc.Field, cc.Reservoir, cc.County, cc.State, cc.OperatorName, cc.BaseApiCode, cc.Location, cc.CaseType, rcat.Label, rclass.Label, 
                  ps.ReportDate, cs.CaseDiscountFactor, corp.Label, cct.Label, cp.Label, rcl.SortId, ProjProject.Label
    ORDER BY rcl.SortId, CaseId
```

When I try to execute this I get the following errors:

`OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".`

`Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".`

Can someone please let me know if I am approaching this the wrong way? Any suggestions or comments are appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Obviously this is not reason for your error but `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` doesn't work with `xlsx` files. Try use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but now I get this error `Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.`

Comment: Install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) provider.